# Why selenium only scrape first page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape this website https://hamariweb.com/news/newscategory.aspx?cat=3. Code is working fine but it only scrape data from first page continuously.
Here is my code

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import time
import os

class WebnewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'webnews'
   allowed_domains = ['www.hamariweb.com']
   start_urls = ['https://hamariweb.com/news/newscategory.aspx?cat=3']
 def __init__ (self):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    self.driver=webdriver.Chrome("C://Users//hammad//Downloads//
    chromedriver",chrome_options=options)

 def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    pause_time = 1
    last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return 
                                               document.body.scrollHeight")

    #start = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in range(10):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight + 400);")
        time.sleep(pause_time)

        url2=response.xpath('.//*[@class="news_img"]/a/@href').extract()
        print("\n\n\n",url2,"\n\n\n")
        new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    self.driver.close()
    #print("\n\n",len(l))
```

Comment: where the code at? Also until unless you say your code to go to the next page how will it parse the next page

Comment: Using Scrapy and Selenium together manually it very error prone. Using an integration package like https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium is highly recommended. Not using Selenium at all is better: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- find latest post/text in the current view.
- execute scroll down over the latest post to trigger 'load more data'

More info:

you can simply do `document.querySelectorAll('#CatNewsList > div').length`
result will be the number of posts.
Iterate over each post and extract the URL:

CSS selector:

> #CatNewsList > div .news_img > a

Now you can get the tag 'href' and extract the link.

When you reach the last post, execute scroll to bottom and wait until for element with XPATH: `//p[text()='loading more news... ']` to be not be VISIBLE.

Like this you are sure, page its not loading anything new.
Keep the previous size of posts and start parsing from it to next length of posts.

Repeat.

Comment: I have edit the question may you please check where the issue is? It scroll down and next elements but only scrape first page elements